# Theming book navigation block to generate drop-down menus

Tags: 6, theming, navigation, nodes

I have a 3 level deep book navigation block. I'd like to change the menu tree HTML output in the following way: For each level of the tree, create a li and inside it put an anchor tag with the active-trail link for that level, and afterwards a ul with the rest of the siblings for that level.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="active-trail level[x]">Level[x] active trail link</a>
    <ul style="display:none;">
        <li><a href="#">Level[x] sibling1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level[x] sibling2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level[x] sibling3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level[x] sibling4</a></li>        
    </ul>
</li>
```

The order of sibling links appearance should be according to their corresponding node weight.

I thought this could be done via the theme_menu_link() function but I can't seem to find a way to pass the current item's depth to the function.

What function do I have to work with in order to achieve what I'm after? Can someone offer some guidance?

Thanks,
Avner

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific theme function, which is used from the Book module for outputting its own block of links to book pages. I am not sure if it suits your case, but you can always use that code to build your own theme function.

The theme function is called from [book_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--book--book.module/function/book_block/6), using the following code:

```
  if (variable_get('book_block_mode', 'all pages') == 'all pages') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Book navigation');
    $book_menus = array();
    $pseudo_tree = array(0 => array('below' => FALSE));
    foreach (book_get_books() as $book_id => $book) {
      if ($book['bid'] == $current_bid) {
        // If the current page is a node associated with a book, the menu
        // needs to be retrieved.
        $book_menus[$book_id] = menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data($node->book['menu_name'], $node->book));
      }
      else {
        // Since we know we will only display a link to the top node, there
        // is no reason to run an additional menu tree query for each book.
        $book['in_active_trail'] = FALSE;
        $pseudo_tree[0]['link'] = $book;
        $book_menus[$book_id] = menu_tree_output($pseudo_tree);
      }
    }
    $block['content'] = theme('book_all_books_block', $book_menus);
  }
```

The [theme_book_all_books_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_book_all_books_block/6) function is empty, because the theme is using a template ([book-all-books-block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_book_all_books_block/6)); as far as I can see, there isn't a preprocess function for that template file.

Comment: Thank you. Took your advice, and used the code you've provided here to build my own theme function. The main idea was to get a flat, one-level array of the book navigation hierarchy, and then split this one array into multiple arrays based on the elements depth. I used this function: book_get_flat_menu($node->book); Probably not the nicest code, but managed to get it to work exactly as needed.